# Change the node edit link for a specific content type

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to be able to change the node edit link from node/[nid]/edit to my_custom_module/[nid] for just one content type. Which hook sould I implement?

I need this change to be applied to all the node edit links present on the frontend and backend of the site.

I tried implementing hook_menu_link_alter but this hook does not provide me any node-related data so I can not apply the link changes just to one content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hook_node_prepare, Please check the below code which can help you to sort out your problem.

```
function hook_node_prepare($node) {
if($node->type == "somecontent type"){
    drupal_goto("/somepath..");
}
```

}